# more rails partials on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, partial-views, instance-variables

I have a rails app. I'm displaying more partials (user, task, conversation, message) from different classes on the users/:id/show page. I set all the instance variables (for other classes as well) in the users.controller's def show action.

It seems to be a bit heavy, so is there a better approach than this? (I'm using @task and @message for the AJAX calls.)

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if Task.between(current_user.id, @user.id).present?
      @tasks = Task.uncompleted.between(current_user.id, @user.id).order("created_at DESC").includes(:assigner).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
      @task = Task.new
      if Conversation.between(current_user.id, @user.id).present?
        @conversation = Conversation.between(current_user.id, @user.id).first
        @messages = @conversation.messages.includes(:user)
        @message = Message.new
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.js { render :template => "tasks/update.js.erb", :template => "tasks/destroy.js.erb", layout: false }
        end
      end
    else
      redirect_to user_profile_path(@user)
    end
  end
```

UPDATED:

users/show:

```
<%if @conversation%>
  <%= render 'conversations/show' %>
<% end %>

<tbody class="newtaskinsert2">
  <%= render partial: "tasks/task_between", collection: @tasks, as: :task %>
</tbody>
```

conversations/_show:

```
<div class="chatboxcontent">
  <% if @messages.any? %>
      <%= render @messages %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="chatboxinput">
  <%= form_for([@conversation, @message], :remote => true, :html => {id: "conversation_form_#{@conversation.id}"}) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_area :body, class: "chatboxtextarea", "data-cid" => @conversation.id %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form_for([@conversation, @message], html: {class: "refile_form"}, remote: true) do |form| %>
      <span class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-file">Choose file
      <%= form.attachment_field :message_attachment, direct: true, presigned: true, class: "choosefile" %></span>
      <%= form.submit "Send File", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-submit-refile", style:"display:none"%>
  <% end %>
  <span id="progresspercent"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep only @user instance variable in the controller, and in partials use: @user.tasks instead of @tasks, @user.tasks.new instead of @task etc. Note also, that you can pass parameters to partials ([3.4.4 Passing Local Variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html))

For sample:

```
<%= render partial: "your_partial", locals: {tasks: @user.tasks} %>
```

Update:

With your way (call methods from class instead of objects) you can do something like it:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if Task.between(current_user.id, @user.id).present? 
    # @user.tasks.where(another_user_field_name: current_user).present? - looks more like Rails way
      @tasks = Task.uncompleted.between(current_user.id, @user.id).order("created_at DESC").includes(:assigner).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
      @conversation = Conversation.between(current_user.id, @user.id).first      
      if @conversation
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.js { render :template => "tasks/update.js.erb", :template => "tasks/destroy.js.erb", layout: false }
        end
      end
      # Do not forget that if @conversation is not exists this code render views by default way
    else
      redirect_to user_profile_path(@user)
    end
  end


<%= render 'conversations/show' %>
<tbody class="newtaskinsert2">
  <%= render partial: "tasks/task_between"%>
</tbody>


<%if @conversation%>
  <div class="chatboxcontent">
    <%= render '_your_messages_partial', locals: {messages: @conversation.messages.includes(:user)}%>
  </div>
  <div class="chatboxinput">
    <%= form_for([@conversation, @conversation.messages.new], :remote => true, :html => {id: "conversation_form_#{@conversation.id}"}) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_area :body, class: "chatboxtextarea", "data-cid" => @conversation.id %>
    <% end %>
    <%= form_for([@conversation, @conversation.messages.new], html: {class: "refile_form"}, remote: true) do |form| %>
      <span class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-file">Choose file
      <%= form.attachment_field :message_attachment, direct: true, presigned: true, class: "choosefile" %></span>
      <%= form.submit "Send File", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-submit-refile", style:"display:none"%>
    <% end %>
    <span id="progresspercent"></span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You can make this code more shorter in case of using relations (@user.conversations instead of Conversation.between... etc)

Comment: Sergey, sry for the prolonged answer. Could you show me via code sample how you would refactor my users/show view and the controller? I updated my question. As you see on the users/show page I render the tasks and the conversation, and in the rendered conversation partial I show the messages/ message forms.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use caching techniques for your views:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#russian-doll-caching

In the extreme scenario where performance is still an issue for you, I would recommend to start denormalising the partials until you re happy with the performance.